# Microsoft Azure AD Graph API: Fetch pro-rated license informations of users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been going through the api docs of Microsoft Azure AD Graph API and am unable to find a way to fetch the prorated licenses of a user.

The problem is that the api only returns the skuids when asked for all the licenses attached to a user.

For e.g.
https://graph.windows.net/#TENANTID#/users/#USERPRINCIPALNAME#/licenseDetails?api-version=1.6

```
"value": [
    {
        "objectId": "VdVcDxIjW0WEg5x0-5H2jbAFlEuId2hFrdGZYU5hO2k",
        "servicePlans": [
            {
                "servicePlanId": "88882e1d05-acd1-4ccb-8708-6ee036647",
                "servicePlanName": "INTUNE_O365",
                "provisioningStatus": "PendingActivation",
                "appliesTo": "Company"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "1209af7827-d63c-4b61-89c3-182f06f82c",
                "servicePlanName": "EXCHANGE_S_STANDARD",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "Company"
            }
        ],
        "skuId": "67buyt0-7788-4568-add1-99614e6ty89",
        "skuPartNumber": "EXCHANGESTANDARD"
    }
]
```

We will be able to identify the tenant subscribed skus from the request https://graph.windows.net/#TENANTID#/subscribedSkus?api-version=1.6

However we cannot figure out when a license(sku) was added/removed to a user. Is such functionality possible via the AADGraph REST API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, if you want to add or remove the license from a user, you can use this Azure AD Graph API :

```
Method : Post

Endpoint : https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/assignLicense?api-version
```

For more details, please refer to [the document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#assignLicense).

Comment: Thanks for your time posting a suggestion. However my query was not on how to add/remove licenses via the api. My intention was to get the data of the licenses added/removed for users in a tenant.

Comment: HI. According to my understanding, you want to get the record of the licenses added/removed for users in a tenant. If so, you can get the record from Audit logs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) in Azure AD.

Comment: If you want to use API to get Audit logs, you can use Reporting API to get it. For more details, please refer to (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-reporting-api).